# Export High Resolution Browser Screenshot

Tags: javascript, blazor, screenshot

For a Blazor WASM project I have been working on, I used this great open-source projects called [Blazor Diagrams](https://github.com/Blazor-Diagrams/Blazor.Diagrams). The client wants me to export a screenshot of the diagram, but with the catch that is that the screenshot should be at the full resolution of the graph which will almost always be higher resolution than the browser window. For example, imagine the div containing the diagram is 900px wide to fit in the browser, but the entire diagram width is 2500px. I would like to capture an image that is 2500px wide.

I have looked into various options like

- html2canvas
- getDisplayMedia

Html2canvas does not play nicely with Blazor and if I understand it right getDisplayMedia would be a pixel for pixel capture.

I don't think we would be able to use 3rd party API's due to confidentiality, so I am wondering what my options would be.

Comment: Do you want to capture the screenshot on the browser side or server? If browser side you could create a hidden div or hidden frame, and draw your graph at a higher resolution to that for the screenshot. If server side you could use puppeteer to programmatically run your page with graph and take a screenshot, which allows you to define a custom viewport and take a png screenshot.

Comment: Hey! One of the users of the library did manage to use html2canvas in SSB. What problem did you get with it? Maybe we can help with that

Comment: I am using Blazor Web Assembly, I should have clarified. When I was using html2canvas I noticed icons were not being rendered, and it seemed like various CSS properties like shadow box didn't look right, but I would be willing to give it another shot! Thanks @Haytam for the response.

Comment: Also adding to this, html2canvas in my recent tests are that the connection lines aren't lining up and sometimes and some are not showing up entirely.

Comment: I'm using Blazor Diagrams and it's possible to render the nodes as SVG, maybe If you could use only SVG nodes it will be simple, you only need a SVG to Image converter

Comment: It appears that my nodes are drawing correctly. It is just the links that aren't rendering correctly. Sometimes they render sometimes they don't. When they do render, they don't render in the correct position. The links are drawn with SVG but the nodes are drawn with divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most if not all of the javascript screen to image, Dom to image library's lack full svg support and has some quirks with in line css etc. Best is to get creative with either playwright or bunit to grab the output html in a staged environment for best results. Currently we had all the issues mentioned but have resolved it in other ways with no/minimal javascript dependencies.

Using Blazor serverside, webassembly might  be a different case

Comment: Can you elaborate on any techniques you used to turn the output html into an image?

Comment: @GeorgeFabish Currently we use playwright in headless mode. Depending on your application complexity you might have to handle authentication.
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/auth

Take a look here on how to get screenshot of elements 

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/screenshots#element-screenshot

Comment: You can play around with the test runner to generate a skeleton of the code (c# or JS) then modify it based on your needs.
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/codegen-intro

Comment: @GeorgeFabish the BUnit approach you may need to place the output of the html on a static page with a stylesheet or inline CSS.

Comment: thanks for the details. I'll see if I can get this to work and report back.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this and finds this useful here is what I did. My project is a Blazor WASM hosted on an IIS server.

- Created a console application that handles the Playwright logic
- Created an API endpoint that when hit, fires up the console application.
- Created a special viewing page for my diagram which does some maths to set the size of the container div to make sure the entire diagram is visible.
- Used playwright to get a screenshot of that particular div.

***Some IIS tips***

In our scenario, I ended up placing the console app exe in the root Websites folder as Node needed read/write access and was throwing errors being inside a subfolder.

I used the following code to install only the chrome browser on first run. This way all the playwright code is located in my Diagram Export app folder.

```cs
string imagesFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "images");
string browserFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "browser");
if (!Directory.Exists(imagesFolderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesFolderPath);
    Console.WriteLine("Created images folder", imagesFolderPath);
}
if (!Directory.Exists(browserFolderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(browserFolderPath);
    Console.WriteLine("Created browser'{0}'", browserFolderPath);
}

Console.WriteLine("Checking dependencies");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH", browserFolderPath);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PLAYWRIGHT_NODEJS_PATH", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ".playwright\\node\\win32_x64\\node.exe"));

Microsoft.Playwright.Program.Main(new[] { "install","chromium" });
```

Had to play around with the auto waiting features on playwright to make sure the page was completely rendered before taking the screenshot. In my case I used the `HoverAsync` API on the last element type to render in my diagram.